# jquery: slide down submenu then clicking on a span only on screens wider than 1050px

Tags: jquery

i have menu with some submenus. my request would be: slide (toggle) down the submenu then clicking the span and do it only on screens wider than 1050px. trick is - there is no span element before i "create" it with this code:

```
$('#main-menu > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a,#main-menu > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a').replaceWith(function() {
 return '<span>' + $(this).text() + '</span>'
 });
```

before:

```
<li><a href="http://piirissaareturism.ee/avasta-piirissaar/">Piirissaar</a>
```

after:

```
<li><span>Piirissaar</span></li>
```

till now all working well. but next - not.

code i created, but which is not working of course:

```
$('#main-menu ul li span:has(.dropdown-menu)').on('click').find('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

**UPDATE**

this one also not working:

```
$('#main-menu ul li span').on('click',function(){
$(this).find('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle();
});
```

common, it can't be so difficult.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Gallex/r4vb2391/) for better overview.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write something like this:

```
$('#main-menu ul li span:has(.dropdown-menu)')
.on('click',function(){
   $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

Otherwise the `on('click')` is not doing anything.

Comment: submenu not opening on click